# phpMyAdmin Authentication Required popup

Tags: phpmyadmin, amazon-rds

I didn't find any data on this issue (which is weird).

I'm using RDS aws database.
I installed mysql + phpmyadmin on another linux centos 7 server in order to login via phpmyadmin to the RDS database.

I edited /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf with my office IP:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
      #Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip <my-ip>
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     #Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
     Allow from <my-ip>
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

I edited /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php in order to work with the RDS configuration by adding this code to the bottom of the file:

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '<rds.host.com>';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'test';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = TRUE;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
```

I set the RDS security group to All traffic (Anywhere) just for this test.

The problem is:

When I go to http://[MY-SERVER-IP]/phpmyadmin I see the login page details, then, when I click on "go", even before I insert the username and password, an authentication popup is displayed and there is no correct user & password for this form. I tried all possible option for this user and password and all are wrong. It is not root and the master password and it is not the DB username and password. Nothing is working and I'm stock on this step.

Anyone knows what's going on with this popup, looks like htaccess & htpasswd thing.

[image]

**Edit:**
I checked if I have .htaccess file under "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/" and I didn't find anything.
Some how the phpMyAdmin interface is blocked by Web Server Authentication Gate but it happens only after I click on "go" button.

Thank you,
Leo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed from

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

and the Auth-basic popup disappeared